# All values of type String of all HashMap became {"bytes":"","empty":false} suddenly

Tags: java, tomcat, hashmap, base64

An confusing error has occurred to one of my containers running stably in production environment. All values of type String of all HashMap became {"bytes":"","empty":false} suddenly，but entity classes are not affected in any way.
This is part of my log data:

```
{
    "image1":{
        "bytes":"dGhpcyBpcyBpbWFnZSAxIHVybA==",
        "empty":false
    },
    "image2":{
        "bytes":"dGhpcyBpcyBpbWFnZSAxIHVybA==",
        "empty":false
    }
}
```

, and the data should be like this :

```
{
    "image1":"this is image 1 url",
    "image2":"this is image 2 url"
}
```

. I guess the data has been Base64, but I don't know any details and how to troubleshoot where the problem is.

And, please forgive my poor English.

Compared with the configuration files of other machines, but no difference.
The error occurred during a http request. The response and part of logs was correct, but part of asynchronous log was error.
After the error occurred, all of data became wrong.
I don't know where the problem is, and I cannot restart my machine to preserve the site.

Comment: Running code doesn't "suddenly" change its behaviour. Something must have changed. Are you sure there hasn't been a deploy of a new version?

Comment: This looks like *something* sets a different type of value to those fields and that then gets serialized suboptimally (the Base64 in your sample decodes to a valid image URL). Where are the `image1` and `image2` fields defined and/or filled? Show us some code that's related to this.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I checked the publish history log with LTZB of our company, and the release time does not coincide with the time the error occurred.@Jorn

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will show some pseudo code later after get home.@JoachimSauer

Comment: Make sure the fields of some backing class have not be incorrectly marked `static`

Comment: Looks like a JSON serialization issue, if the entity classes have not changes, then my guess (and just a guess) would be some custom serializer was being used before. Check a few things, if the code is using Jackson/Other JSON library, if there were any custom serializer or other mechanism being used before to convert the object value of the Base64 encoded to decoded. My hunch would be some entity class annotation is being lef out